# hooked up with a nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a nullpointerexception. Only thing is, it doesn't appear to be there at all devices, so is rather strange to me..

An idea could be that **Bitmap src could be null?** But since I initialize it in front this is not possible? I guess? Since it is not happening on my own device I just have to be sure...

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(C.getResources(), resId);
Bitmap result = mark(bm);

public static Bitmap mark(Bitmap src) {
        int w = src.getWidth();
        // int w = 150;
        int h = src.getHeight();
        // int h = 150;
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setTypeface(font);
        paint.setTextSize(15);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawText("Hi", 10, 15, paint);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As we do not have the stack trace, I assume you get your exception on the first line of mark(): `int w = src.getWidth();`.

That means that indeed src is null. It is possible as `public static Bitmap decodeResource (Resources res, int id)` can return null if it the image cannot be decoded.

You should therefore dig into your available ressources. Maybe on the faulty device a png is missing?

Comment: Normally it isn't.. it just gets the resources from the app itself, the image is used in the activity, and this is used to share it and adds a watermark... So if it wouldn't be in resources I would get the error on another line as well?

Comment: Ok, I was asking because sometimes if you miss an image in one of the res folder, you might get this kind of error.
If it's not a local resource I would therefore look for hardware specificity that may cause different behaviour. Do you know which device is concerned by this problem?

Comment: I must say, that in the current version it hasn't the C.getResources() but just getResources()... could adding the C. be the solution?

Comment: I see that the error occure at Android 1.5 and 2.1-update1, could this be a cause?

Comment: Do you have access (in your stack trace) to "Phone Model"? This will give you a hint for hardware relative issues.

If the problem is more "android version relative" than hardware, you might want to dig into folders: I remember a problem with "res" and "assets".

Comment: Different models... Winners are: Motorola_i1, Motorolla MB300 (Android 1.5), T-Mobile myTouch 3G (Android 1.6), LGE GT540, Cricket M860, SEMC E15i (Android 2.1-update1)... Seems more Android version related, don't you think? Is there away to go around this and at least display a message like not supported on your device or something? Or isn't this a proper solution

Comment: You should google for this devices just in case (something like "android camera Motorola_i1 resources issues" maybe).
Now for android version workaround you can do this: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) { //display some popup to inform that this feature is not supported }`.

Comment: To be sure I want to check if it is null.. I tried Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), resId);
   if(bm == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not supported by this Android version", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
   res = mark(bm); But this gives me still the same error.. Strange, no?

Answer (score 0):

DecodeResources can return null if there's any problem with the decoding.  That may be what happened here.

Comment: What's the best way to fix this? Add a if(src != null) { }? Or maybe I can fix that error in the decoding?

Comment: Fixing the decoding would be best, but I don't know why it failed.  You'd have to figure that out yourself.  If you just want to get rid of the crash quickly, yes put an if(src!=null) and you can avoid the crash.

Comment: Yeah the problem is it doesn't happen on my own device... so difficult for me to track.. Also a problem: if it is null, the result that will be returned is useless of course?